# Connected and uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with zero measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is also uncountable, connected and of zero measure?

Comment: An open subset has non-zero measure and is uncountable.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh except for the empty set. :-)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you. And if I removed the requirement that the set is open?

Comment: Connected, null uncountable subset exists if $n\ge 2$. You can check that every non-singleton connected subset of $\Bbb{R}$ contains an open interval so there is no such set for $n=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n>1$ that set of course exists: any line has zero mesure in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$. In $\mathbb R^1$ instead, an infinite connected set contains a line segmnent, which has always positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.